# SPSS for loop based on a variable

Tags: loops, for-loop, macros, spss

I'm just learning SPSS and I want to do simple subgroup analysis based on a variable "status" I created which can take values from 0 to 8. I would like to print outputs in one go.

this is the pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
for( i = 1, i = 8, i++)
{
filter by (ststus = i)
display analysis
remove filter
}
```

That way I can do it all in one go but also i can add to the analysis code and do something easily for the 8 subgroups.

I don't know if it's relevant but here is the code I want to iterate over currently:

```
USE ALL.  
COMPUTE filter_$=(Workforce EQ 1 AND SurveySample = 1 AND State = 1).
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'Workforce EQ 1 (FILTER)'. 
> VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'.  FORMATS filter_$
> (f1.0).  FILTER BY filter_$.  EXECUTE.
> 
> 
> FREQUENCIES VARIABLES = Q86 Q33 Q34 Q88 FSEScore    /BARCHART FREQ   
> /ORDER=ANALYSIS.
> 
> CROSSTABS    /TABLES=FSEScore BY Q86    /FORMAT=AVALUE TABLES   
> /CELLS=ROW    /COUNT ROUND CELL.
> 
> FILTER OFF. USE ALL.
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably a very getto way of doing this, the suggestion above is probably more sensible.

You can initialise Python is spss. The following code works:

```
begin program.
import spss

for i in xrange(1,8):
    string = str(i)
    spss.Submit("""
        USE ALL.
        COMPUTE filter_$=(Workforce EQ 1 AND SurveySample = 1 AND Status = %s). 
        VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'Workforce EQ 1 (FILTER)'. 
        VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'. 
        FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0). 
        FILTER BY filter_$. 
        EXECUTE.

    #analysis as required
    FREQUENCIES VARIABLES = Q86 
          /BARCHART FREQ 
          /ORDER=ANALYSIS.    

    """%(' '.join(string)) )
end program.
```

Many thanks to eli-k I probably should have just used splitfile.

Answer (score 3):

`split file` command may solve the problem - it causes your analysis reports to show results for each category of your split variable separately:

```
*run your transformations.
sort cases by status.
split file by status.
FREQUENCIES .....
CROSSTABS ....
split file off.
```

If this is not enough, you can use a macro to run through "status" categories:

first define the macro:

```
define MyMacro ()
!do !ST=1 !to 8
* filter commands using **status = !ST**
* transformations using **status = !ST**
    FREQUENCIES .....
    CROSSTABS ....
!doend
!enddefine.
```

now call your macro:

```
MyMacro .
```

Comment: thanks I'm trying to work through this... Can you prototype functions in SPSS the way you can do it in python or c?